# Sprite passing through immovable wall?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

So I'm trying to make a simple maze in Phaser.js, but collision has been a pain. I have gotten to the point where I can detect collisions between the sprite and my wall, but the sprite passes right through, even though I set the wall as immovable. Pretty new to phaser and js as a whole so it's probably something simple lol

```
    create() {
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()
        this.wall50x100 = this.physics.add.image(300,200,'50x100').setImmovable()
        this.sprite = this.physics.add.sprite(200,200,'sprite')
        this.sprite.setOrigin(0,0)
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        this.wall1 = this.physics.add.image(500,200,'50x100').setImmovable()
        this.wall1.setOrigin(0,0)
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        this.back = this.add.image(50,500,'back')
        this.back.setOrigin(0,0)
        this.back.setInteractive()

        this.back.on('pointerup',function(){
            this.scene.start('Scene2');
          },this)    

        this.add.text(20, 20, "Scene: 3", {font: "25px Arial", fill: "green"});
        this.physics.add.collider(this.sprite, this.wall50x100, function(sprite, wall50x100){
            console.log('Collision Detected')
        }.bind(this))
    }
```

I was expecting the sprite to not pass through the wall, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

There are atleast two posibile reasons I can think of, why the collision might not work:

1. You are not moving the Sprite with *"physics"*, you are setting the position of the sprite, instead of with velocity or acceleration. If you move the sprite by setting the `position` you override the phaser - "physics".
2. Or the physics-bodys are to small or/and the sprite is moving to fast, so that they passthrough each other, without triggering a collision.

But it could be many other thing, these where the top two I could think of without seeing more code.

> btw.: Following this [Stackoverflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for examples might help you get better answer and also help you find you problem on you own. *(p.s.: Voting and/or accepting answer might also help. having question, without accepted answer, own better solution, comments or some other form of engagement, might deter people from answering. )*

> **Tipp:** depending on you maze you could think about using a `tilemap`. Checkout this [official examples](https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=tilemap/&q=), for some examples.